# How to change CSS based on mobile device?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

In the following example, I want to display only one `div`, depending on the device.

I'm familiar with how to use `@media` to override a CSS class but not how to do a conditional.

```
<style type="text/css">
   @media (max-width : 770px) {
     ...
   }

  @media (max-width : 320px) {
   ...
  }
  //do I need another for the desktop?
</style>

//if desktop
<div style="width: 400px; float: left;">
    this is desktop
    <a href="somepage.html"><img src="aLargeImage.png"/></a>
</div>

//if mobile
<div style="width: 200px; float: left;">
    this is mobile
    <a href="somepage.html">just text</a>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here but all you want is to show the different div elements depending on what screen size the user visiting are on?

Comment: Whether or not the content is hidden, the user will still end up downloading it.  A lot of people pay by the KB on their mobile plans these days.

Comment: Not that many.  Lots of plans are unlimited data. But not really a way around per KB issue.  I think hide/show these two divs is the solution.  I just need to use different class names.

Comment: @imbuedHope for all we know, the typos could be the reason it is not working (or a copy/paste error) - edits like that could be the part of the answer but should not modify the problems already present in the question

Answer (score 29):

Here's an example of how it can be done conditionally without javascript:

```
//CSS
.visibledevice {display:none;}
.visibledesktop {display:display;}

@media (max-width : 320px) {
    .visibledevice {display:block;}
    .visibledesktop {display:none;}
}

//in the page
<div class="visibledesktop">this displays for desktop and tablet</div>

<div class="visibledevice">this displays for mobile</div>
```

Comment: And how you define the div class in first place ? is the two div will rendered in HTML no matter what device is .! in this case we will render two div with same contents on the page . from SEO aspects I no think it good idea KW density will be doubled.    
last I voted up as the solution still better than Js solutions

Comment: @fdrv it can't unless you use user-agents.

Answer (score 9):

Hm i think its easier to create 2 or more css files and load them via javascript based on the device. Something like that inside the onload function:

```
var cssPath = "standard.css";
if (navigator.platform == "iPad")
    cssPath = "iPad.css";

var fileref = document.createElement("link");

fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
fileref.setAttribute("href", cssPath);

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Shorter and more readable css files easy to exchange.

Comment: I'd like to avoid javascript.

Answer (score 7):

how to do a conditionnal css media query :

```
@media only screen and (width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {    
    .selector1 { width:960px; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In such simple cases that's all you need:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Try to use e.g. `width:100%` or `max-width` - rather than fixed widths.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old thread but i figured a better option.. for me at least

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">
<?php 
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
{   echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/styles/mobile.css">';
}
else{
echo '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/styles/desktop.css">';
};
?>
```

Comment: I get a warning: `Notice: Undefined variable: useragent in [...] line [...] ` using your code. I guess is the `$useragent` at the end of the line. Can you explane?