# BootStrap Row Content Stick to Left in Mobile View

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am creating a Web Page with Bootstrap.

This webpage displays a list of cards which display as expected in a desktop view, but when switching to a mobile view the cards display in an undesired manner.

In the mobile view the cards stick to the left side of the display. I want these to be centered instead.

Below are images displaying the issue along with the code that controls the cards:

**Desktop View:**
[image]

**Mobile View:**
[image]

**Card Code:**

```
<h3 style="padding-left: 8%; padding-top: 2%; font-family: 'Verdana';">Your Listen Later</h3>
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 7%;">
    {% for i in watch reversed %}
    <div style="padding-left: 2%; padding-top: 1%;">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="{{i.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{i.name}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text" style="color: green;">Tags: {{i.tags}}</p>
                <p class="card-text" style="color: green;">Movie: {{i.movie}}</p>
                <a href="/musicbeats/songs/{{i.song_id}}" class="btn btn-outline-danger ">Listen Song</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML that is generated by this code so that we can see how it looks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the same paddings to the left and right side of the `.row` so that the spacing is symmetrical. Then make the `div` before the `.card` full-width and add the same side paddings again:

```
<h3 style="padding-left: 8%; padding-top: 2%; font-family: 'Verdana';">Your Listen Later</h3>
  <div class="row" style="padding-left: 7%; padding-right: 7%;">
    {% for i in watch reversed %}
    <div style="padding-left: 2%; padding-right:2%; padding-top: 1%; width:100%">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img src="{{i.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{i.name}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text" style="color: green;">Tags: {{i.tags}}</p>
        <p class="card-text" style="color: green;">Movie: {{i.movie}}</p>
        <a href="/musicbeats/songs/{{i.song_id}}" class="btn btn-outline-danger ">Listen Song</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

In general, I wouldn't recommend the approach you have been using - since you have Bootstrap available, you can familiarize with the [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and utilize the containers, rows and columns, so that you wouldn't need those percentage-based paddings and inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet:

```
<h3 style="padding-left: 8%; padding-top: 2%; font-family: 'Verdana';">Your Listen Later</h3>
<div class="container">
    {% for i in watch reversed %}
    <div class="row mx-auto">
        <img src="{{i.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{i.name}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text" style="color: green;">Tags: {{i.tags}}</p>
            <p class="card-text" style="color: green;">Movie: {{i.movie}}</p>
            <a href="/musicbeats/songs/{{i.song_id}}" class="btn btn-outline-danger ">Listen Song</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I have added a `<div>` with a `container` class and changed the `<div>` within the for statement to have a class of `row` and `mx-auto`.

The `container` Bootstrap class establishes that this is where the main contain website will be. Within this content, there will be gird classes such as `rows` and `columns`.

Because you only want one element per `row`, there is no use for the `columns` class for the `<div>`; each independent entry will have it's own `row`.

The `mx-auto` Bootstrap class will center the image by setting both the margin on the left and right to auto.

**However**, this will solution provided will **only** work for the mobile view. Here is a resource looking into how you can change styles based on what device you are on: [Change Styles based on Display Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156225/how-to-change-css-based-on-mobile-device).

Make sure you implement the capability to switch from one layout to another based on this size. I would usually do so using PHP, displaying different code/styles based on the current size.